# can't we use SQL WINDOW FUNCTION in ms access?

Tags: ms-access, window-functions

The query is as below, I have an query in MS Access with OVER statement like this, but it does work out and MS Access said I have an error 3075 (sth like sql syntax error):

```
SELECT tank.OpsDate, tank.QTY, SUM(tank.QTY) OVER (ORDER BY tank.OpsDate ASC) AS runningTotal
FROM tank
ORDER BY tank.OpsDate;
```

I needed a running total over an inventory report. I checked 100 times that the syntax should be ok. :( hope anyone can help me over coming this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that ACCESS does not support SQL window functions.

I worked it out a method to get runningTotal in MS Access environment. I run DSUM to calculate running total from another query containing the date, tank and quantity data. I post it below for other's reference:

```
SELECT tank.OpsDate, tank.QTY, 
DSUM("QTY","zAllTank",OpsDate<=#"& tank.OpsDate &"# AND tank_ID=" & tank.ID) AS runningTotal
FROM tank
ORDER BY tank.OpsDate;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using DSum in queries is usually slow. Try with a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    tank.OpsDate, 
    tank.QTY, 
        (Select Sum([QTY]) 
        From zAllTank 
        Where zAllTank.OpsDate <= tank.Opsdate And zAllTank.tank_ID = tank.ID) 
        As RunningTotal
FROM 
    tank
ORDER BY 
    tank.OpsDate;
```